# Data is not displaying when argument is passed through variable , working with Hardcoded value in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am using @api variable in my LWC to pass argument to Apex controller and returning the values, however data is returned back but not displaying on LWC page, same is working when I pass the value through Hard-coded value.

Parent HTML

```html
<c-participant-onboarding-relationship child-prj-id="a1qM00000037jYwIAI"></c-participant-onboarding-relationship>
```

.JS

```js
@api childPrjId;
 @wire(getProjectAccountRole, {
    //  recordId: 'a1qM00000037lMgIAI' 
      recordId: "$childPrjId"
  })
```

In above example recordId: 'a1qM00000037lMgIAI' is working fine
But when I pass the value with recordId: "$childPrjId" data is not getting displayed on LWC page.

However I can see the data in Apex logs and Console in both the cases.

Please help.

Comment: Might need to see some more context. This code appears that it should work.